# Detect if object is empty or not

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to detect if an object has data or not but this doesn't seem to work:

```
if(item.sellers.length != 0) {
```

Full code:

```
.each(response, function(i, item) {
       if(item.sellers.length != 0) {
            $.each(item.sellers, function(index, value) {
              $('#modal-table tbody').append("<tr><td></td><td><strong>Seller:</strong></td><td>" + index + "</td><td>"+ value + "</td>");
            });
       });
```

json is as follows:

```
response = 
    {
        "5": {
            "name": "surgeon bueno",
            "country": "Spain",
            "antiquity": "renewal",
            "amount": "2686.97 USD",
            "sellers": {
                "Frank": "2690.58 USD",
                "Bob": "1690.58 USD",
            }
        },
        "11": {
            "name": "Alex Lloyd",
            "country": "American Samoa",
            "antiquity": "new client",
            "amount": "0.0 USD"
        },
        "12": {
            "name": "alex lloyd",
            "country": "Aruba",
            "antiquity": "new client",
            "amount": "0.0 USD"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please give us more information, and if possible, the best way to do so is to do it with fiddle or codepen.

Comment: We need to see the definition of `item` e.g. what are you iterating through?

Comment: Depends on what you define as empty. If you mean if it has no properties, use `Object.keys(item.sellers).length == 0`. If you want to check if all properties have no value/undefined/null then you need to check them individually

Comment: you can use $.isEmptyObject( object ).

Comment: I added the json @ristapk

Comment: empty is not the same as not existing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `hasOwnProperty`:

```
if(item.hasOwnProperty("sellers")) {
    // each loop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (item.sellers.length != 0) {
```

You can use objects directly inside `if()`

```
if (item && item.sellers) {
    // write your functionality
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case check every object:

```
if(item!=null && item.sellers!=null && item.sellers.length != 0)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On this question I am posting an simple solution to check whether the jquery object has any child or not this can be checked using javascript function
here is the code

```
var x=new Object();    
x.name='Scott';    
console.log(x);    
console.log(isempty(x));    
console.log(x.name); 

function isempty(obj)    
{    
  if(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(x).length===0)
    return true
  else 
    return false
}
```