# Iterate through object key that has no name

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following object:

```
response = 
    {
        "5": {
            "name": "surgeon bueno",
            "country": "Spain",
            "antiquity": "renewal",
            "amount": "2686.97 USD",
            "sellers": {
                "Frank": "2690.58 USD",
                "Bob": "1690.58 USD",
            }
        },
        "11": {
            "name": "Alex Lloyd",
            "country": "American Samoa",
            "antiquity": "new client",
            "amount": "0.0 USD"
        },
        "12": {
            "name": "alex lloyd",
            "country": "Aruba",
            "antiquity": "new client",
            "amount": "0.0 USD"
        }
    }
```

And I iterate over all values and display them in a new row in a table as follows, I would like to add a new row for those that have `"sellers"` in the JSON eg. like `"surgeon bueno"`, how can I iterate through them as well and display a new row if they exist? As they don't have key names.

This is the code as it stands, I now want to add a row if they have sellers and display that data.

```
  $.each(response, function(i, item) {
            $('#modal-table tbody').append("<tr class='grey'><td>" + item.name + "</td><td>" + item.country + "</td><td>" + item.antiquity + "</td><td>" + item.amount + "</td>");

         });
```

This is new code compared to original post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [detect if object is empty or not jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636048/detect-if-object-is-empty-or-not-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to iterate using vanilla Javascript:

```
for (var i in response) {
    $('#modal-table tbody').append("<tr class='grey'><td>" + response[i].name + "</td><td>" + response[i].country + "</td><td>" + response[i].antiquity + "</td><td>" + response[i].amount + "</td>");
}
```

This will iterate over the object and set `var i` to every key.

```js
$(function() {
  var response = {
    "5": {
      "name": "surgeon bueno",
      "country": "Spain",
      "antiquity": "renewal",
      "amount": "2686.97 USD",
      "sellers": {
        "Frank": "2690.58 USD",
        "Bob": "1690.58 USD",
      }
    },
    "11": {
      "name": "Alex Lloyd",
      "country": "American Samoa",
      "antiquity": "new client",
      "amount": "0.0 USD"
    },
    "12": {
      "name": "alex lloyd",
      "country": "Aruba",
      "antiquity": "new client",
      "amount": "0.0 USD"
    }
  };

  for (var i in response) {
    $('#modal-table tbody').append("<tr class='grey'><td>" + response[i].name + "</td><td>" + response[i].country + "</td><td>" + response[i].antiquity + "</td><td>" + response[i].amount + "</td>");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="modal-table">
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```